# How to get symbol after section title to on new line?

Tags: section-titles

How to get (without titlesec) title number centring and symbol after it?

[image: section]

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\S}{\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\huge\fontspec{Symbola}}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\quad\Roman{section}} % quad is kinda ugly and adding centre here didn't work. 

\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}%\@endsection {\T} % adding symbol here didn't work.
                }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{section}{2}
\section{Cycle} % bonus points if just this work
%\section[Cycle]{\\Cycle\\\T} % is there a better way to get than this? 
%\section[Fire]{\\Fire\\\T}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the symbol you're trying to get? I'm not sure the copy-paste worked properly.

Comment: `^^^^1013A` ``, but the placement of the symbol is the relevant part.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `titlesec`?

Comment: @Vincent: Maybe the O.P. prefers to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

The `titlesec` package is really useful to format section titles.

I could not insert the specific symbol in your example, so I replaced it with the standard section symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand*{\T}{\S}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\centering\bfseries\Large}{\Roman{section}}{\parskip}{}[\T]
\begin{document}
\addtocounter{section}{2}
\section{Cycle}
\section{Fire}
\end{document}
```

Just change the definition of `\T` to output the symbol you want.